# How do you pass a function as an argument to another function, but the initial function's arguments change?

Tags: python, function, syntax

How can you write a function f that takes another function g as an argument, but where function g has arguments that change dynamically depending on what happens in function f?

A pseudocode example would be:

```
def function(another_function(parameters)):  # another function passed as an argument, with parameters
    for i in range(10):
        print(another_function(i))
```

So when i iterates, function f is called with a new argument i every time. How could that be implemented?

I found one can use *args as a parameter, but did not see how it could be implemented.

Cheers

Comment: IIUC, you would just pass another_funciton to function (without parameters).  thus: `def function(another_function): ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create a function that takes two parameters. The first parameter is a reference to a function and the other is a parameter to be used by that function

```
def func1(func, p):
    func(p)

func1(print, 'Hello world!')
```

So we call func1 with a reference to the built-in *print* function (doesn't have to be built-in - could be any function that's in scope)

**Output:**

```
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is almost correct. You could simply write:

```
def function(another_function):
    for i in range(10):
        print(another_function(i))
```

In Python, functions are simply objects, just like numbers, strings and lists and thus don't need special syntax to be used like this.